# Register Layout not showing first time

Tags: java, android

Whenever i verify phone number with OTP then it should go to Register Layout but it returns to login layout. But when i close the app and run it again then it directly jumps to register layout.

I had check the code several times but not able to find the error.

here is the sample video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elfg7bS3Cig

Here is my code

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static int LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE = 6262; //Any number you want
    private List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener listener;
    private Uri filePath;
    private ImageView img_drive_proof;
    private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 22;


    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar)
    ProgressBar progress_bar;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference driverInfoRef;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        delaySplashScreen();
    }

    private void delaySplashScreen() {
        progress_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Completable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(() ->
                        //After show Splash Screen, ask login if not login
                        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
                );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (firebaseAuth != null && listener != null)
            firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(listener);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        driverInfoRef = database.getReference(Common.DRIVER_INFO_REFERENCE);

        providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        );

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        listener = myFirebaseAuth -> {
            FirebaseUser user = myFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null)
            {
                //Update Token
                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()
                        .getInstanceId()
                        .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(instanceIdResult -> {
                            Log.d("TOKEN",instanceIdResult.getToken());
                            UserUtils.updateToken(SplashScreenActivity.this, instanceIdResult.getToken());
                        });
                checkUserFromFirebase();
            }
            else {
                showLoginLayout();
            }
        };
    }

    private void showLoginLayout() {
        AuthMethodPickerLayout authMethodPickerLayout = new AuthMethodPickerLayout
                .Builder(R.layout.layout_sign_in)
                .setPhoneButtonId(R.id.btn_phone_sign_in)
                .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.btn_google_sign_in)
                .build();

        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(authMethodPickerLayout)
                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .build(),LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, response.getError().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkUserFromFirebase() {
        driverInfoRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                        {

                            DriverInfoModel driverInfoModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(DriverInfoModel.class);
                            goToHomeActivity(driverInfoModel);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            showRegisterLayout();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void showRegisterLayout() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.DialogTheme);
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_register,null);

        TextInputEditText edt_first_name = (TextInputEditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.edt_first_name);
        TextInputEditText edt_last_name = (TextInputEditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.edt_last_name);
        TextInputEditText edt_phone = (TextInputEditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.edt_phone_number);
        img_drive_proof = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_drive_proof);

        Button btnUpload = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
        Button btn_continue = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

        img_drive_proof.setOnClickListener(v -> SelectImage());
        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(v -> uploadImage());

        //Set data
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber() != null &&
                !TextUtils.isEmpty(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber()))
            edt_phone.setText(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber());

        //Set View
        builder.setView(itemView);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        btn_continue.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt_first_name.getText().toString()))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter first name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt_last_name.getText().toString()))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter last name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt_phone.getText().toString()))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                DriverInfoModel model = new DriverInfoModel();
                model.setFirstName(edt_first_name.getText().toString());
                model.setLastName(edt_last_name.getText().toString());
                model.setPhoneNumber(edt_phone.getText().toString());
                model.setRating(0.0);

                driverInfoRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .setValue(model)
                        .addOnFailureListener(e ->
                                {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                        )
                        .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Register Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            goToHomeActivity(model);
                        });
            }
        });
    }

    private void goToHomeActivity(DriverInfoModel driverInfoModel) {
        Common.currentUser = driverInfoModel;
        startActivity(new Intent(this,DriverHomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

you are probably not clearing your previous activity by providing a flag while firing the intent. pass clear top flag here:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,DriverHomeActivity.class));
```

Comment: i am really new to this. will you please tell me how to do that. and i have similar code in another project that's working fine.